# How to load the same module multiple times with different configurations?

Tags: css, sass, configuration

I'm using an scss spinner library, I need to use different spinners, and I need to load the module in different scss files that are @used all on the same main file. So, simplyfied:

```scss
    main-style.scss
      @use "_page-bottom-form.scss"
      @use "_navigation-tools-shared.scss"

    // where both are in turn @using "loaders.scss" as * with( $configuration ) //
```

I get this error:

```
Dart Sass failed with this error: This module was already loaded, so it can't be configured using "with".
  ┌──> parts/components/_page-bottom-form.scss
5 │ ┌ @use "../../node_modules/spinthatshit/src/loaders.scss" as * with(
6 │ │   $loader-color: $white,
7 │ │   $loader-size: 5px,
8 │ │   $loader-gap: 5px
9 │ │ );
  │ └─^ new load
  ╵
  ┌──> parts/structure/_navigation-tools-shared.scss
4 │ ┌ @use "../../node_modules/spinthatshit/src/loaders.scss"  as * with(
5 │ │   $loader-color: $mid-grey,
6 │ │     $loader-size: 20px,
7 │ │     $loader-height: 20px,
8 │ │     $loader-border-size: 3px,
9 │ │ );
  │ └─^ original load
  ╵
  parts/components/_page-bottom-form.scss 5:1  @use
  parts/_main-style.scss 16:1                  @use
  style.scss 2:1                               root stylesheet
```

How can I avoid it, maintaining my current scss files structure/tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#with-mixins) says, there is a solution for that using **mixins**. You can add some codes like below to `loaders.scss` file:

```
$loader-color: #000 !default; /* This is the color that library has defined itself for example. */
@mixin configure($loader-color-me: null) {
  @if $loader-color-me {
    $loader-color: $loader-color-me !global;
  }
}

@mixin styles {
  .loadMain {
    color: $loader-color;
  }
}
```

Then you can modify your `scss` files as follow:

> _navigation-tools-shared file:

```
@use "loaders" as load1;

.loader1 {
  @include load1.configure($loader-color-me: #2589FF);
  color: load1.$loader-color;
}
```

> _page-bottom-form file:

```
@use "loaders" as load2;

.loader2 {
  @include load2.configure($loader-color-me: #FF89FF);
  color: load2.$loader-color;
}
```

With that modifications, If you use `@use "your-path/to/main";` and for example have 3 `<p>` tag in your html as follow, you will give 3 different color for each one:

> html file:

```html
<p class="loader1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci consectetur corporis delectus, dignissimos dolores doloribus ex minima modi molestiae molestias natus, nesciunt quam, qui quis recusandae sapiente sit voluptas!</p>
<p class="loader2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus aliquam at cum cupiditate dolores est hic iure laudantium maxime minus nulla, provident quam qui rerum sapiente, tempore tenetur voluptate voluptates.</p>
<p class="loadMain">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda culpa delectus deserunt dolorem expedita facere fugiat harum labore libero maxime molestias nesciunt nisi perferendis, quas suscipit tempora totam unde voluptates!</p>
```

Comment: Your snippet is not working, stackoverflow editor doesn't support sass syntax (!!!) Anyway I'll give it a try

Comment: @LucaReghellin I saved the codes in a [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-hhqvxv?file=/src/App.vue). You can test it there.